# Listview disappears after getting fetched in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, widget, provider

I'm using Firebase as a backend and for some reason in this widget whenever i fetch the data from firestore the listview appears for a second and then disappears until i press the profile icon in the bottomAppBar below then it's there. And if i switch between widgets it disappears again so i have to press the icon below again to show it.

This is a gif of the bug:
https://i.imgur.com/UkyV0wJ.gif

I'm using provider and i noticed this error in the console when i implemented this listview:
Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I literally did the same thing in my Home Widget and it works fine, from the provider to the set up inside the classes, and i made sure that all my data are received correctly and no firebase exceptions are occuring.
here is how my code works:

```
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
 @override
  void initState() {
    UserPostNotifier userPostNotifier =
        Provider.of<UserPostNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    DatabaseServices()
        .getUserPosts(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid, userPostNotifier);
    super.initState();
  }
...
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserPostNotifier userPostNotifier = Provider.of<UserPostNotifier>(context);
...
Scaffold and stuff here
...
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ProfilePost(
        content: userPostNotifier.userPostList[index].content,
        areCommentsAllowed:
            userPostNotifier.userPostList[index].areCommentsAllowed,
        index: index,
      );
    },
    itemCount: userPostNotifier.userPostList.length,
  )
```

And here is my Notifier class:

```
class UserPostNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  
  List<UserPost> _userPostList = [];
  UserPost _currentUserPost;

  UnmodifiableListView<UserPost> get userPostList =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_userPostList);

  set userPostList(List<UserPost> userPostList) {
    _userPostList = userPostList;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set currentUserPost(UserPost userPost) {
    _currentUserPost = userPost;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  UserPost get currentUserPost => _currentUserPost;
}
```

I added the provider to my multiprovider this way too:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<UserPostNotifier>(
      create: (context) => UserPostNotifier(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could identify by the code you put, you have:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserPostNotifier userPostNotifier = ....
```

This means that every time your widget tree is rebuilt, a new instance of UserPostNotifier is created and assigned to userPostNotifier and this is your problem.

A quick solution and in the absence of knowledge of your code, is to declare the userPostNotifier at the beginning and you test if the variable is null in the builder, if it is, you do the assignment.

```
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
UserPostNotifier? userPostNotifier;

....

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (userPostNotifier == null) {
        userPostNotifier = Provider.of<UserPostNotifier>(context);
    }
```

That way you will always use the same instance... I think using a different instance in initState is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. However i tried your solution and it didn't make a difference. I had the same thing in my Home feed and it works fine like i mentioned before. If you need any more code to know what's going on feel free to ask or suggest anything.